# i got error in if statement while i using the solidity version 0.5.0;

Tags: contract-development, contract-debugging

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
```

...

```
function SearchByTenderId(string memory a) public view returns(string){
    string memory Id=a;
    if(keccak256(TenderId) == keccak256(Id)){
        return "TenderId is already existing,\n We con't Reapply";
    }
    else{
        return "We can apply for tender";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your arguments to `bytes32` when using `keccak256` which you can do with `abi.encodePacked()`.

Like this:

`if(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(TenderId)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(Id))){`

Hope it helps.